# Get only one column from DetachedCriteria with multiple Projections

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria, detachedcriteria

I have the following code to get the object which has the "Andamento" with the latest date (I have called date -> data).

```
DetachedCriteria criteriaAndamento = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Andamento.class);
criteriaAndamento.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
        .add(Projections.max("data").as(null))
        .add(Projections.groupProperty("processo").as("id"))
);
criteriaAndamento.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("DATE_FORMAT(`data`, '%d/%m/%Y') like '" + filter.getFilterValue().toString() + "%'"));
criteria.add(Property.forName("id").in(criteriaAndamento));
```

But in this line of code: `criteria.add(Property.forName("id").in(criteriaAndamento));` it gives the following error:

```
ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:129 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)...
```

So it expects the detachedCriteria to have only 1 column. But since I need both projections, how can I select only one column? Or maybe remove the other?

ps: I have removed the "max" projection and it works, so I need some way to select only the "processo" column from this detachedCriteria.

Comment: Hi, have you found solution?